# Inductor polarity

Tags: pcb, filter, inductor, antenna, polarity

By looking on the picture of the inductor [PE-0402CL470JTT](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Pulse-Electronics/PE-0402CL470JTT?qs=EBDBlbfErPxxS3npfPqH%252BA%3D%3D) and the datasheet, we can notice a black pole and a white pole for the inductor.

Is there any difference between poles?

The datasheet doesn't help to find out the difference, if I'm not wrong.

Could you please help to find out the difference between poles.

Thank you.

Comment: Strange finding.

Comment: There shouldn't be any inductor polarity as far as there are no coupled windings. inductor polarity doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 4):

It's good practice to have a polarity marking on an inductor because of additive or subtractive cross-talk between identical inductors used multiple times in close vicinity on the same circuit board. The markings don't prevent cross-talk but at least if you observe the correct inductor polarity, you can guarantee that another build of the same PCBA will behave the same way.

Comment: I see , thanks for your advice